# ubuntu on chroot apt-get update fail - Unable to parse package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, chroot

When I chroot under Ubuntu 12.04 and run `apt-get update` in my chroot home, I get:

```
100% [21 Translation-en gzip 0 B] [22 Translation-en bzip2 3E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_precise_main_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch  

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Translation-en Encountered a section with no Package: header             

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/xxx
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/xxx/sys
mount -t proc none /mnt/xxx/proc
mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/xxx/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/xxx/dev/pts
mount -o bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/xxx/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /mnt/xxx
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.